# How can I use Python 2 on Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, python-2.x

How can I use the earlier version of Python i.e version 2.x?

Under the 'change runtime' option - I can see the option for selecting hardware accelerator.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use these 2 shortcuts to create a Python 2 Colab.

- `bit.ly/colabpy2`
- `colab.to/py2`

They will forward to this URL.

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#create=true&language=python2

## Update 2022

Now the Python 2 kernel is removed. The simple method above no longer works. You may try the difficult method I used with Python 3.10 if you really must.

Comment: Thanks for sharing , how did you created it?
I have not been able to access the Runtime type option earlier.

Comment: The option is removed. But this is the direct link to the old menu: "Create Python 2 Notebook".

Comment: As of August 15th 2022, Python 2 is no longer available in Colab

Answer (score 15):

Python 2 reached its end of life on January 1, 2020, and is no longer supported by the Python developer community. Because of that, Colab is in the process of deprecating Python 2 runtimes; see https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#python-2-deprecation for details.

Presently, there is no way to change to Python 2 via the Colab UI, but existing Python 2 notebooks will still connect to Python 2 for the time being. So, for example, if you open a notebook like this one: https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jakevdp/de56c474b41add4540deba2426534a49/empty-py2.ipynb and execute code, it will execute in Python 2 for now. I would suggest following that link, and then choosing **File->Save A Copy In Drive** to get your own copy of an empty Python 2 notebook.

But please be aware that at some point in the future, Python 2 runtimes will be entirely unavailable in Colab, even for existing notebooks that specify Python 2 in their metadata.

Comment: The colab link does not work any more as of today.

Answer (score 2):

Python2 is deprecated now and is no longer available as a runtime in colab

Answer (score 0):

If you are running some python program, you can use
`!python2.7 your_program.py` instead of `!python your_program.py`

But if you want to execute some python2.7 code, I think that as mentioned in the previous answers, it is not possible.