# theano.function() throws up a long exception in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, theano, lasagne

I am using Google Colab to run the BinaryNet Neural Network implemented using theano by the authors of the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02830)  here: https://github.com/MatthieuCourbariaux/BinaryNet

When I run the following line from /Train-time/mnist.py (line 199):

```
train_fn = theano.function([input, target, LR], loss, updates=updates)
```

Colab throws up this error:

> You can find the C code in this temporary file:
> /tmp/theano_compilation_error_5_e2lq4v library
> inux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33, is not found.   library
> inux-gnu/7/include-fixed/limits.h:194, is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/7/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7, is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/7/include-fixed/limits.h:34, is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:298:1: is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:298:1: is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33, is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/7/include-fixed/limits.h:194, is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/7/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7, is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/7/include-fixed/limits.h:34, is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:298:1: is not found.  library
> inux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:298:1: is not found.
>
> Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node',
> Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 + (i0 * round3(clip(i2, i3, i4)))) *
> i5)}}[(0, 2)](TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 2.0}, TensorConstant{(1, 1) of
> -1.0}, Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 + (i2 * i3 * i4) + i5))}}.0, TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 0}, TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 1},
> Elemwise{Composite{Cast{float64}(LT(i0, i1))}}[(0, 0)].0), '\n',
> "Compilation failed (return status=1):
> /root/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.19.104+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic-x86_64-3.6.9-64/tmp9q80fef3/mod.cpp:932:2:
> warning: character constant too long for its type.  ['V15_tmp2'] =
> round(['V15_tmp1']);.   ^~~~~~~~~~.
> /root/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.19.104+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic-x86_64-3.6.9-64/tmp9q80fef3/mod.cpp:932:23:
> warning: character constant too long for its type.  ['V15_tmp2'] =
> round(['V15_tmp1']);.                        ^~~~~~~~~~.
> /root/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.19.104+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic-x86_64-3.6.9-64/tmp9q80fef3/mod.cpp:1054:2:
> warning: character constant too long for its type.  ['V15_tmp2'] =
> round(['V15_tmp1']);.   ^~~~~~~~~~.
> /root/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.19.104+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic-x86_64-3.6.9-64/tmp9q80fef3/mod.cpp:1054:23: warning: character constant too long for its type.  ['V15_tmp2'] =
> round(['V15_tmp1']);.                        ^~~~~~~~~~.
> /root/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.19.104+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic-x86_64-3.6.9-64/tmp9q80fef3/mod.cpp: In member function ‘in...

I used this to install theano and lasagne:

```
!pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Theano/Theano/archive/master.zip
!pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip
```

I am using the exact same code as in the github repo with the only difference being that I used keras to import the mnist dataset instead of pylearn2

Could someone please help me figure out why this is happening? Thank you!

EDIT

I ran my code in python 2.7 and it worked! [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61479832/14033035) deals with using python 2 in Colab.